# Unexpected EOF error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, eof

I am just learning python and do not understand why the following simple code doesn't work:

```
while True:
    try:
        print "Counter 1: %(counter)"
        counter += 1

        if counter > 15:
            break
```

Comment: Don't you need an `except` or `finally` block for your `try` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing of `try` expression. So:

```
while True:
    print ("Counter %s": %(counter))
    counter += 1

    if counter > 15:
        break
```

Will be better

But if you study please review following solution:

```
for i in range(0, 15):
    print ("Counter %s": %(counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you used `try:`, you need to have `except` clause:

```
while True:
    try:
        print "Counter 1: %(counter)"
        counter += 1

        if counter > 15:
            break
    except StandardError:
        print 'Foo'
```